# Can we install and use Qt platform and its plugins in Ubuntu 20 server for HPC-AI

Tags: qt, tensorflow, deep-learning, hpc, ubuntu-server

While running a TensorFlow based Deep learning model in Graph mode execution, I got the error:

> qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/username/.conda/envs/slt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.

> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
> Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc.
> Aborted (core dumped)

I am running my code on a server via a local remote host and it's a ubuntu 20 Server-based single user os. ( That is no GUI Based Desktop Manager).

*What is the above error mean?*

If I'm not wrong and according to my understanding, QT Platform and its plugins are not installed. So how to install the QT Platform in the ubuntu server if my assumption is correct.

If not how to solve the above error. Can anyone please help me out

Comment: No, the problem is that you are starting a GUI application in a server where the X server or other GUI server is not running.

Comment: Not GUI application, my tensorflow code need QT platform for execution and in my server there is no Desktop manager or GUI. Just single user mode.But has three more user(Standard user)

Comment: @shrivassp It seems that your app is not GUI but tensorflow does use Qt to generate some GUI, so 1. you should find a way to make tensorflow not use Qt(maybe disable some submodule), 2. Install and use xvfb, also run: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 ./your_app`

Comment: Thanks a lot @eyllanesc , i will try what you suggested me...!

Comment: @shrivassp Looking better at the error message I see that you are using opencv, have you installed opencv?

Comment: Yes, Im using it and i have installed it